# PayPal integration in JavaScript app

Tags: javascript, cordova, paypal

I m developing a Cordova application (mobile and web). I need to integrate a payment service like PayPal, for in-app micropayment purchases.

I noticed two services on the PayPal's website: Braintree and Express Checkout. Actually I cannot use the Braintree service (braintreepayments.com) because I need to receive money exclusively on my PayPal account, no matter the customer pays using PayPal or direct credit card.

So, I think the best way to go is Express Checkout. I saw [this link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/express-checkout/) and it seems that two methods are available: vzero and REST calls.

I think vzero would be better because of their mobile compatibility, but when I try to search informations about vzero, I m always getting informations about Braintree.

So I m a bit confused between vzero, Express Checkout, PayPal and Braintree and I don't know what to use to fit my needs.

Any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v.zero implementation on PayPal's site is a PayPal specific version of braintree. It allows you to, in the future, transition to Braintree for DCC, Venmo, Apple Pay, Bitcoin, etc, but allows you to use just PayPal for now. With that implementation, you will have braintree functionality using only PayPal without having to have a braintree dashboard.

v.zero using PayPal would help with your mobile functionality, for sure, but you have more range of current options with the NVP/SOAP or REST versions of Express Checkout.